# Group G having two ends

Tags: geometric-group-theory

Let $Z$ set of integer is a subgroup of G. $Ends(G)=2$. Is it true that $Z$ is of 
finite index in G ?
I was trying to show quasi isometry between $Z$ and $G$. 
For notation and other definition please refer to the book Bridson and Haefliger
page 144-146 
http://www.math.bgu.ac.il/~barakw/rigidity/bh.pdf

Comment: Hint: What do you know about algebraic properties of $G$? Another hint: First consider the case when $G$ is torsion-free.